# Swift Self as associated type bound in protocol

Tags: swift, generics, type-constraints, associated-types

I want to force an associated type to be `Self`, but the compiler is having none of it.
Here's what I want to get to compile:

```
protocol Protocol {
    // Error: Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Self'
    associatedtype Type: Self
}
```

You might ask, why not just use `Self` instead of an associated type? Simply because I cannot: the associated type is inherited from a parent protocol. And it doesn't make sense to change that in the parent protocol.
Here's something similar to what I'm trying to do:

```
protocol Factory {
    associatedtype Type

    func new() -> Type
}

protocol SelfFactory: Factory {
    associatedtype Type: Self // Same Error
}
```

Edit:
matt's answer is almost what I'm looking for. It behaves like I want it to at runtime, but is not restrictive enough at compile time.
I want this to be impossible:

```
protocol Factory {
    associatedtype MyType
    static func new() -> MyType
}

protocol SelfFactory: Factory {
    static func new() -> Self
}

final class Class: SelfFactory {

    // Implement SelfFactory:
    static func new() -> Class {
        return Class()
    }

    // But make the Factory implementation diverge:
    typealias MyType = Int

    static func new() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

I'd like the `typealias` in `Class` to trigger a redeclaration error or similar.

Comment: The error message is absolutely right. The source of the problem is indicated in your words: "the associated type is inherited from a parent protocol". No it isn't. Protocols don't do "inheritance". You can't "override" one protocol with another as you seem to be trying to do. You either adopt the protocol or you don't.

Comment: "I'd like the typealias in Class to trigger a redeclaration error or similar" You cannot prevent overloading! `f()->Int` and `f()->String` can _always_ coexist in Swift. You are asking the language to be a different language. You are not the compiler. — To put it another way, adoption of a protocol does not prevent me from implementing other methods not required by the protocol!

Comment: It is unclear what you want and why. What would satisfy you? Maybe your best bet is to have two _unrelated_ protocols, Factory and SelfFactory. And I adopt just _one_ of them. Would _that_ make you happy? (But of course even then you cannot stop me from adopting both of them if I feel like it.)

Comment: @matt [here's](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=88726a8e50a60b8de81f265ca67e5f3e) some real code, in rust, that shows what I'm after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to say this?

```
protocol Factory {
    associatedtype MyType
    func new() -> MyType
}

protocol SelfFactory: Factory {
    func new() -> Self
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I'm after. I edited the question with more details. Thanks for answering!

Comment: After spending some more time battling with this, I believe this is currently the best solution. I would like to be able to say that `SelfFactory`'s implementation of `Factory` is "final", but I guess that's not going to happen. And having to repeat every function definition is annoying, but oh well.

Comment: Actually, this still works if I define `SelfFactory` as an empty protocol, and implement the `new` method in an extension.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an old question, but you can do this as of [Swift 4.0](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md):

```
protocol Factory {
    associatedtype MyType
    static func new() -> MyType
}

protocol SelfFactory: Factory where MyType == Self { }
```

Aren't where clauses great?